# Is it possible in vscode liveshare to share port 443 (https)?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur, vscode-liveshare

I'm trying to share the port 443 from my development machine (win10) to my laptop (os x) using the amazing Live Share feature of Visual Studio Code.

On the dev machine I can access the service (running behind an nginx reverse proxy), so server is running fine.

VS Code doc mention a 1:1 mapping for the port "unless it's already in use".

Checking with `sudo lsof -P -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN` on the mac, I can confirm 443 is not in use.

But the port on the mac is mapped to a random port (50150 in this case) instead of 443.

I guess I'm lacking some rights to open a sub 1000 port on os x.

Does anyone know what I can do (I mean other then running vscode as root)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (for anyone who would find this later) : not possible!

Restricted ports are ... restricted.

And as I said in the question i don't want to run vscode as root.
But what I ok to run as root is a small utility to do port forwarding.
So I'm now using portforward (npm -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/portforward ) to do just that, and everything works fine.

Comment: If it's convenient, could you share your solution on port forwarding ?

Comment: it's literally portforward : https://www.npmjs.com/package/portforward